# Invalid UUID/Services returned while scanning paired devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am trying to find a specific type of device based on its services from the list of already paired devices, but when I get the devices UUID, none of the services supported by the device actually show up.

I don't want to `device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);` to every single device paired to eventually find the right one, due to it being inefficient.

The relevant segment of code is as follows

```
            for(BluetoothDevice device : bondedDevices) {
                ParcelUuid temp_uuids = device.getUuids();
                for (ParcelUuid uuids : myUuids) {
                    if (uuids.equals(temp_uuids)) {
                        targetDevice = device;
                        return targetDevice;
                    }
                }
            }
           Log.d(TAG, "Target Device Not Found");
           return targetDevice;
```

the `if (uuids.equals(temp_uuids))`statement where it checks equals is never met, I believe my bluetooth device is supposed to add the GATT service UUID under its list of services included in SDP, but for some reason it is not being detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding and my work-around to my own question:
Problem: there is not a be BLE connection started yet and thus I am reading the Bluetooth Classic services rather than BLE. Thus, reading the incorrect ones. (Not sure this is true for all Android versions or just Android 10)

To solve this, I fell back onto to primary checking the address of the Bluetooth device. This is due to my goal of only connecting to a certain brand of device and them having only a set of specific vendor address. I am then checking UUIDs after connection is made.

Hope this helps whoever faces this issue in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds unreliable. `getBondedDevices` returns only earlier paired devices. `getUuids` provides the local copy of the service UUIDs assuming services are  discovered in the first place.

Use [startScan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)) with desired service UUIDs in [ScanFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter) to get all nearby devices fulfilling filters.

Comment: the reason I am using using ```getBoundedDevices``` is because I only want to scan already paired devices first. Wouldn't ```startScan``` not work if the device is already paired?